# Filter Function TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, filter, typeerror

I want to filter a list of tuples to exclude any tuple that contains 0 as its first value.

Hi, if this question is a duplicate - I apologize, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

I want to use the filter function so that a list of tuples, which excludes any tuple that contains 0 as its first value, is returned.

For example: Instead of getting , [(6, 1), (0, -1)] the output should be [(6, 1)]

and I'm using the following list:
`function_terms = [(3, 2), (-11, 0)]`

I can write:

```
    derivs = []
    for term in function_terms:
        if find_term_derivative(term)[0]!=0:
            derivs.append(find_term_derivative(term))
    return derivs
```

but I'm looking for something like this, in which I can use the filter function.

```
    derivs = []
    for term in function_terms:
        derivs.append(find_term_derivative(term))
    return list(filter(lambda t: derivs[t][0] != 0, derivs))
```

However, with the second function I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

How am I using the filter function incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first approach would be vastly superior, you are already looping over `function_terms`. In any case, what you need would be `filter(lambda t: t[0] != 0, derivs)` the argument to the predicate function is already going to be the element in `derivs`, not the indices (wouldn't make much sense since you can filter *any iterable*, not just indexable iterables...)

Comment: Also, no need to call `find_term_derivative(term)` twice, unless you meant to do that, but to me, it seems like it would be needlessly inefficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this clears it up perfectly! thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish. The first step is to compute the derivatives, and the second step is to filter out all of the terms with a zero as the first element.

```
derivs = [find_term_derivative(term) for term in function_terms]
return list(filter(lambda term: term[0] != 0, derivs))
```

Comment: This helps! thanks, with your answer and the comment from  juanpa.arrivillaga - I get that I was primarily using the lambda function incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Maybe*** try this instead:

```
derivs = []
    for term in function_terms:
        derivs.append(find_term_derivative(term))
    return list(filter(lambda t: t[0] != 0, derivs))
```